# I am having trouble loading data using sqlite3 in jupyter notebook with the following error message: 'no such table: rental'

Tags: python, database, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I am doing a data analysis with Python course and I am struggling to load the salika.db data base to perform some analysis. salika.db is saved in the same location as the notebook.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import sqlite3 as sql

%matplotlib inline

conn = sql.connect('sakila.db')

df = pd.read_sql('''
    SELECT
        rental.rental_id, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date,
        customer.last_name AS customer_lastname,
        store.store_id,
        city.city AS rental_store_city,
        film.title AS film_title, film.rental_duration AS film_rental_duration,
        film.rental_rate AS film_rental_rate, film.replacement_cost AS film_replacement_cost,
        film.rating AS film_rating
    FROM rental
    INNER JOIN customer ON rental.customer_id == customer.customer_id
    INNER JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id == inventory.inventory_id
    INNER JOIN store ON inventory.store_id == store.store_id
    INNER JOIN address ON store.address_id == address.address_id
    INNER JOIN city ON address.city_id == city.city_id
    INNER JOIN film ON inventory.film_id == film.film_id
    ;
''', conn, index_col='rental_id', parse_dates=['rental_date', 'return_date'])
```

I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:2202, in SQLiteDatabase.execute(self, sql, params)
   2201 try:
-> 2202     cur.execute(sql, *args)
   2203     return cur

OperationalError: no such table: rental

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 5
      1 # Loading the data
      3 conn = sql.connect('sakila.db')
----> 5 df = pd.read_sql('''
      6     SELECT
      7         rental.rental_id, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date,
      8         customer.last_name AS customer_lastname,
      9         store.store_id,
     10         city.city AS rental_store_city,
     11         film.title AS film_title, film.rental_duration AS film_rental_duration,
     12         film.rental_rate AS film_rental_rate, film.replacement_cost AS film_replacement_cost,
     13         film.rating AS film_rating
     14     FROM rental
     15     INNER JOIN customer ON rental.customer_id == customer.customer_id
     16     INNER JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id == inventory.inventory_id
     17     INNER JOIN store ON inventory.store_id == store.store_id
     18     INNER JOIN address ON store.address_id == address.address_id
     19     INNER JOIN city ON address.city_id == city.city_id
     20     INNER JOIN film ON inventory.film_id == film.film_id
     21     ;
     22 ''', conn, index_col='rental_id', parse_dates=['rental_date', 'return_date'])

File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:635, in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize, dtype_backend, dtype)
    633 with pandasSQL_builder(con) as pandas_sql:
    634     if isinstance(pandas_sql, SQLiteDatabase):
--> 635         return pandas_sql.read_query(
    636             sql,
    637             index_col=index_col,
    638             params=params,
    639             coerce_float=coerce_float,
    640             parse_dates=parse_dates,
    641             chunksize=chunksize,
    642             dtype_backend=dtype_backend,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    643             dtype=dtype,
    644         )
    646     try:
    647         _is_table_name = pandas_sql.has_table(sql)

File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:2266, in SQLiteDatabase.read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize, dtype, dtype_backend)
   2255 def read_query(
   2256     self,
   2257     sql,
   (...)
   2264     dtype_backend: DtypeBackend | Literal["numpy"] = "numpy",
   2265 ) -> DataFrame | Iterator[DataFrame]:
-> 2266     cursor = self.execute(sql, params)
   2267     columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   2269     if chunksize is not None:

File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:2214, in SQLiteDatabase.execute(self, sql, params)
   2211     raise ex from inner_exc
   2213 ex = DatabaseError(f"Execution failed on sql '{sql}': {exc}")
-> 2214 raise ex from exc

DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
    SELECT
        rental.rental_id, rental.rental_date, rental.return_date,
        customer.last_name AS customer_lastname,
        store.store_id,
        city.city AS rental_store_city,
        film.title AS film_title, film.rental_duration AS film_rental_duration,
        film.rental_rate AS film_rental_rate, film.replacement_cost AS film_replacement_cost,
        film.rating AS film_rating
    FROM rental
    INNER JOIN customer ON rental.customer_id == customer.customer_id
    INNER JOIN inventory ON rental.inventory_id == inventory.inventory_id
    INNER JOIN store ON inventory.store_id == store.store_id
    INNER JOIN address ON store.address_id == address.address_id
    INNER JOIN city ON address.city_id == city.city_id
    INNER JOIN film ON inventory.film_id == film.film_id
    ;
': no such table: rental
```

I expected it create a dataframe from the data specified in my code.

Comment: Seems like there's no table rental. Or you have no access to it. Can you do `select * from rental`.

Comment: You might also download an application for viewing SQLite files, such as "DB Browser for SQLite", and open the salika.db file on your file system. You will see that it is probably empty or doesn't have that table.